# Using bluemix web IDE in DevOps Services for transferring files sometimes doesn't work

Tags: web, ide, ibm-cloud, devops

I use a feature of the Web IDE where I drag and drop a files (.html or ,png) from a Windows Folder into a folder in the left Nav of the Bluemix DevOps web editor (i.e into public .. images).  It seems to work sometimes and not others.  When it works, I drag a file with my left button from the windows folder over to the folder in the left nav of the web IDE, which turns a green teal color ( sometimes has marching ants around it). I let go and then a progress bar shows up while it up loads and the file appears in that directory.  When it works it is great, but then for some reason I try the exact same thing and nothing happens after I let go of the file over the teal folder. I use mostly Chrome, but also Firefox.  Is there a setting or set of conditions that would cause this not to work sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug it I suggest to follow the network trace of chrome developer tools and check what is failing
Anyway I suggest you to check the session opened on the webIDE page: you could be taking the page opened for a long time without updating remotely and it makes your session to expire and the next upload to fail.

Comment: This is one thing I saw in the network trace log.   

apps?Name=NodeCloudDB&Target=%7B%22Org%22%3A%22scurtis%40us.ibm.com%22%2C%22Space%22%3A%22dev%22%2C%22Url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ng.bluemix.net%22%7D (canceled) xhr xhr.js:175 0 B 15.00 s 
region (canceled) xhr xhr.js:175 0 B 5.00 s